# Ajuda em um logica PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, array

Estou com um grande problema **para mim***

***segue abaixo como está sendo feito o select no banco.***

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

#
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Character-Encoding: utf-8');
define( 'MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'MYSQL_USER', 'root' );
define( 'MYSQL_PASSWORD', '' );
define( 'MYSQL_DB_NAME', 'sistema' );
//$PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . MYSQL_DB_NAME, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD );
try
{
  $PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . MYSQL_DB_NAME, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD );
}
catch ( PDOException $e )
{
    echo 'Erro ao conectar com o MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


$sql = "SELECT tblinvoices.id, tblinvoices.clientid, tblinvoices.status, tblinvoices.duedate, tblclients.company, tblclients.website from tblinvoices INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblinvoices.clientid = tblclients.userid where tblclients.id = 1 ";


$result = $PDO->query( $sql );
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


 $json_str = json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


echo $json_str;
```

Tenho um retorno em JSON . esse abaixo .. vou exibi-lo para explicar minha situação;

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-09-05",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "8",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-10-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "15",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-11-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "16",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-11-03",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "17",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-11-03",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "24",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-12-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "31",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-01-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "40",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-02-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "47",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-03-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "60",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-04-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "61",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "4",
    "duedate": "2018-05-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "68",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "4",
    "duedate": "2018-05-03",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
}
```

]

Beleza até ai! 
O que eu quero fazer e pegar o status e fazer uma condição;
exemplo :
se o status for igual a 4 informo olha esta atrasado.. 
se o status for igual a 2 informo Que está OK.

então fiz assim **básico**:
 *Esse CURL coloco la dentro do codigo do cliente. assim para dar a mensagem lá;*

```
$cr = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/clientes/"); 
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//definindo uma variável para receber o conteúdo da página...
$retorno = curl_exec($cr);
//fechando-o para liberação do sistema.
curl_close($cr); //fechamos o recurso e liberamos o sistema...


$dados = json_decode($retorno, true);

if ($dados[0]['status'] == 4) {
echo "Olha Vencido";
}elseif ($dados[0] == 2) {
  echo "Que Beleza você esta em dia.";
}else{
  echo "tem alguma coisa errado.";
}
```

Mais como podem ver tem vários retornos com com status iguais , dai começa meu problema, quero pegar somente os status(4) *vencido*, se eu fizer essa alteração que esta vindo la do meu banco, fazendo um where status = 4 , nao vou conseguir validar,  se esta em dia status(2) ou não.
Outro questão é pegar pelo id, mais eu encontrei outro problema, se o ID mudar o que vai ocorrer ja que o fatura e gerada todo o mês. 
Não estou conseguindo chegar em uma logica.

Onde eu pego o status das ultimas faturas, e faço minha condição;

Desculpe o testo longo. e que queria explicar o máximo, se alguem puder me dar uma luz.

Comment: Então resumindo o que você quer: varrer todos os dados e retornar os que tem status 4 para fazer alguma lógica seguinte, correto?

Comment: O que você quer fazer não está muito claro na sua explicação. Mas de uma forma resumida. Você só deve trazer do banco de dados o que você precisa. Não deve trazer outros valores para excluí-los via PHP. A menos que você precise desses valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir dos dados que você recebe pelo JSON, você pode obter apenas os registros que deseja utilizando a função `array_filter`. Para aumentar a legibilidade do código, podemos definir um enumerador com os status existentes:

```
abstract class Status {
    const ATRASADO = 4;
    const EM_DIA = 2;
}
```

Assim, para obter os registros atrasados, pode fazer:

```
$atrasados = array_filter($data, function ($it) {
    return $it->status == Status::ATRASADO;
});
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DutifulIntentionalAdvance) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/xYBJ7h) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/2029f80546b5ad6bdd73179b1348dac1)</sup>

Desta forma, você pode percorrer `$atrasados` sabendo que todos esses estão com o `status` igual a 4. O mesmo pode ser feito com o `status` igual a 2 ou qualquer outro valor possível.

Answer (score 1):

Olha, se eu entendi bem, você está com dificuldades em acessar os dados, um a um, do seu array criado a partir do objeto JSON.
Vou lhe sugerir o exemplo abaixo utilizando a função [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) do PHP

```
<?php
$ret = '[
{
    "id": "1",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-09-05",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "8",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-10-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "15",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-11-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "16",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-11-03",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "17",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-11-03",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "24",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-12-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "31",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-01-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "40",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-02-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "47",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-03-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "60",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-04-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "61",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "4",
    "duedate": "2018-05-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "68",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "4",
    "duedate": "2018-05-03",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
}
]';

$dados = json_decode($ret, true);


foreach ($dados as $transacao){
    echo 'A transação id: '.$transacao["id"].', referente a '.$transacao["duedate"].' está ';
    if($transacao["status"] == "4")
        echo 'vencida';
    elseif($transacao["status"] == "2")
        echo 'em dia';
    else
        echo 'aprensentando problemas';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

terá o seguinte retorno:

```
A transação id: 1, referente a 2017-09-05 está em dia
A transação id: 8, referente a 2017-10-06 está em dia
A transação id: 15, referente a 2017-11-06 está em dia
A transação id: 16, referente a 2017-11-03 está em dia
A transação id: 17, referente a 2017-11-03 está em dia
A transação id: 24, referente a 2017-12-06 está em dia
A transação id: 31, referente a 2018-01-06 está em dia
A transação id: 40, referente a 2018-02-06 está em dia
A transação id: 47, referente a 2018-03-06 está em dia
A transação id: 60, referente a 2018-04-06 está em dia
A transação id: 61, referente a 2018-05-06 está vencida
A transação id: 68, referente a 2018-05-03 está vencida
```

**EDIT**

ou ainda, para retornar os id's das que tem `status = 4`

```
<?php
$ret = '[
{
    "id": "1",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-09-05",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "8",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-10-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "15",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-11-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "16",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-11-03",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "17",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-11-03",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "24",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2017-12-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "31",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-01-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "40",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-02-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "47",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-03-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "60",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "2",
    "duedate": "2018-04-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "61",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "4",
    "duedate": "2018-05-06",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
},
{
    "id": "68",
    "clientid": "1",
    "status": "4",
    "duedate": "2018-05-03",
    "company": "Cliente Exemplo",
    "website": "clienteexemplo.com"
}
]';

$dados = json_decode($ret, true);

$ids = "";
foreach ($dados as $transacao)
    if($transacao["status"] == "4")
        $ids .= $transacao["id"].', ';

if($ids)
    echo 'A(s) transação(ões) com o(s) id(s): '.substr($ids,0,-2).' estão vencidas';
else
    echo 'Não há transações vencidas';
```

retorna:

```
A(s) transação(ões) com o(s) id(s): 61, 68 estão vencidas
```